# stripe registerElement not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use [Example2 from stripe](https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/blob/master/js/example2.js)

my jscript is

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
      var stripe = Stripe('test key');
      var elements = stripe.elements();
      example2.js per link above
</script>
```

I am getting an error on the last line of example2.js

```
registerElements([cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc], 'example2'); (Not Defined)
```

Suggestions welcome.. thanks

Comment: did you succeed in implementing elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, there's a bug in the repo...
You can fix it by importing the function from [here](https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/blob/614dc1033a33d6fa30948085385449b69260333e/js/index.js)

```
function registerElements(elements, exampleName) {
  var formClass = '.' + exampleName;
  var example = document.querySelector(formClass);

  var form = example.querySelector('form');
  var resetButton = example.querySelector('a.reset');
  var error = form.querySelector('.error');
  var errorMessage = error.querySelector('.message');

  function enableInputs() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      form.querySelectorAll(
        "input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='tel']"
      ),
      function(input) {
        input.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
    );
  }
```

You should submit an issue to the owner of the repo [here](https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/issues)

Comment: Stripe is so freakin lazy sometimes. These samples are just sloppy.

Comment: This throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null'

Comment: This snippet is incomplete and not working, see full code here https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/js/index.js

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that - in 2021 - GitHub can do this :

[image]